# Adding only new records to my database

Tags: database, sqlite, grails

I am trying to access a SQLite database (that basically reads info about phones connected to network) , retrieve info and store them into my domain variable's to be stored in the webservice (that view the only of connected phone) database. The thing is I retrieve all the info every 5 secs, and want to add to my database the new records only(new connected phones). what is the proper method to do that?

Comment: Is the id of the table incremental ?

Comment: the id of my database yes(but that doesn't help since the data is coming from the sqlite db), however am not sure about that of the one i am retrieving the info from, when i select * from the table i get : 
[TMSI:1, CREATED:1412843151, ACCESSED:1412843498, APP_FLAGS:0, IMSI:415037501027961, IMEI:[null], L3TI:0, A5_SUPPORT:[null], POWER_CLASS:[null], OLD_TMSI:1417548777, PREV_MCC:415, PREV_MNC:3, PREV_LAC:702, DEG_LAT:[null], DEG_LONG:[null]]
this is the oneraw from the table

Comment: The field created is probably the date of creation of the raw in timestamp. If is it the case, all you need to do is to get the data created (using this field) after the max value of your new DB. You definitively need to check the discrepancies. You want me to add this in an answer ?

Comment: i just found out. The TMSI is auto incremented so that serves for id,so i can read only bigger value ids than i have . the created is a Unix time of record creation i will need that for connection time.

Comment: Yes, it is probably the best you can do. Be sure to check discrepancies between the two tables using this method.

Comment: I'm working on a SQLite plugin that uses a 3rd-party library to wrap the native SQLite API with the JDBC API. That will let Hibernate create and execute SQL like it does for SQL databases (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) If you can wait one or two more days I can make a beta version available and once we iron out any issues I'd think it could be released over the weekend

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I'm really found of your works(book, plugins, your answers here) thanks for all your works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two approach that I could think of:

1.Have a variable that saves the last rows `id` and every time you want to retrieve data from your database, just read data with bigger `id` than what you have in your variable.(this could only work if your `id` is incremental)

2.Add another boolean column to your database and make it `true` when you read that row, and every time you read from database just query rows which that column in them are false.

I personally prefer the first approach.

Comment: this helps if i am copying the table as it is, but when i only read the info and save it into another database using different variables it wont do the work.
this is 1 raw from the sqldb:
[TMSI:1, CREATED:1412843151, ACCESSED:1412843498, APP_FLAGS:0, IMSI:415037501027961, IMEI:[null], L3TI:0, A5_SUPPORT:[null], POWER_CLASS:[null], OLD_TMSI:1417548777, PREV_MCC:415, PREV_MNC:3, PREV_LAC:702, DEG_LAT:[null], DEG_LONG:[null]]
suppose i am showing active phones, i will store the IMSI from this table in mine, if a new one connects i am reading both, but i only want to add the latter.

Comment: also records will not always be there, the first phone might disconnect, and then connect later on. so it wont have a fixed id. the only thing fixed is the TMSI and IMSI of the phones, thats their identity and i should do something around that to store only new ones.

Comment: what are they? TMSI looks incremental to me, could you provide more data?

Comment: yes TMSI is incremental i actually found the source file to the db, now i can save only higher valued TMSIs, but the thing is if a phone disconncted/reconnected it will have a new TMSI and be saved again
i think i should compare entries using the IMSI since it is unique to each phone

Comment: @HusseinShehady make a column unique is very easy in groovy/grails it is actually easy when you use ORM in every language, IMSI unique: true will do the work for you